# Increased heap size in java is not reflecting in jconsole

Tags: java

**strong text**

1. I am trying to run an java spring boot application by specifying the heap size as argument while starting the jar like below,

> java -jar a-1.0.0.jar -Dpidfile=/tmp/a_report.pid -Xmx5196m -Xms512m
>   -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp/java_heapdump.hprof

Max Heap Space - 4 GB

But when I try to monitor the application after execution in J-Console, I could not see the actual heap size change getting reflected. I could see in Memory tab the following params

> Time:  2018-02-13 15:23:42 Used: 
>       73,103 kbytes Committed:   1,181,184 kbytes Max:   1,864,192 kbytes

Also the application throws OOM exception when the heap size is around 2 gb so it is clear that the updated heap space memory given during the start of the application is not getting reflected.

So what should I do to make my application pick heap space as 4gb

> Configuration :
>
> RAM - 8 gb JDK - 1.8

Comment: `-Xmx5196m` this value does not look like 4GB.. Please change to correct value and try. Also take note which version of java you are using and whether it's 64 or 32 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the options **before** `-jar a-1.0.0.jar`, otherwise they're interpreted as arguments for the jar, not for the JVM.